# How can I make content behind a partly transparent navbar disappear?

Tags: html, css, web, navbar

I have a partly transparent navbar on top of my page:

```
<div class="navbar">
   Content
</div>
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: rgba(212, 0, 255,0.3);
}
```

The background of the page is a canvas.

The problem is that when i scroll down, the content doesn't disappear behind my navbar because the navbar is partly transparent.
I only want the page background and the navbar show up in the navbar area and not the content

Answer (score -1):

### Use This!

```css
.navbar {
position: absolute !important;
}
```

Comment: can you share me link so I just solve your problem perfectly